# Pandas Multiindex DataFrame - group by external series?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame with two indexes; it looks like this:

```
>>> by_hour
                                  pr         da     delta   delta_sq
node         timestamputc                                           
A            1             20.540423  21.093659  0.553237   9.869976
B            1             17.675580  18.183104  0.507524  11.474762
C            1             16.257307  16.961944  0.704638  68.023460
...                              ...        ...       ...        ...
X            24            20.649155  20.805145  0.155990  43.176084
Y            24            20.677271  21.183925  0.506655  47.746125
Z            24            21.455556  21.725556  0.270000  39.393092

[60312 rows x 4 columns]
```

I have another DataFrame with a single index, identical to the level 0 index of `by_hour`:

```
>>> nodes
               type
node                 
A                type 1
B                type 1
C                type 2
...                 ...
X                type 3
Y                type 1
Z                type 2

[2513 rows x 1 columns]
```

I would like to group the first DataFrame by the "type" column of the second DataFrame, while preserving the level 1 index, to get an output like this:

```
                            pr        da        delta      delta_sq 
type     timestamputc
type 1   1
         2
         ...
type 2   1
         2
...
type n   1
         ...
         24
```

How can I do this? Is it possible without creating an intermediate DataFrame?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This aggregates the DataFrame by type and timestamp:

```
node_type = nodes.loc[by_hour.index.get_level_values('node'), 'type'].values
timestamp = by_hour.index.get_level_values('timestamputc')
by_hour.groupby([node_type, timestamp]).sum()


                            pr         da     delta   delta_sq
       timestamputc                                           
type 1 1             38.216003  39.276763  1.060761  21.344738
       24            20.677271  21.183925  0.506655  47.746125
type 2 1             16.257307  16.961944  0.704638  68.023460
       24            21.455556  21.725556  0.270000  39.393092
type 3 24            20.649155  20.805145  0.155990  43.176084
```

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm looking for--the resulting dataframe has the same number of rows as the initial by_hour data frame. I'm trying to aggregate the by_hour dataframe by node type.

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work. There are still just as many rows as there are in the original by_hour table. It is not aggregating by type.

Comment: Yes. No dice. FWIW, I'd rather drop the existing index on this table anyway--it's large, takes time to rebuild, and I have further analysis to perform with it. But that aside, it is not giving the output I need. The result of the groupby has the same dimensions as the original table. I have found another solution that I will write up as an answer.

Comment: Scratch that; alternative solution doesn't work either.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to my alternative (referred to in the previous comment), not yours. Your new solution is great--it does exactly what I was looking for, and I've upvoted and accepted the solution.